# Engineering formatter function doesn't upper round

Tags: java, gwt, numbers, string-formatting

I have this function that format big numbers.

```
public static String ToEngineeringNotation(Double d, String unit, int decimals) {
        double exponent = Math.log10(Math.abs(d));
        if (d != 0)
        {
            String result = "0";
            switch ((int)Math.floor(exponent))
            {
                case -2: case -1: case 0: case 1: case 2:
                    result = (d + "").replace(".", ",") + " " + unit;
                    break;
                case 3: case 4: case 5:
                    result = ((d / 1e3) + "").replace(".", ",") + " k" + unit;
                    break;
                case 6: case 7: case 8:
                    result = ((d / 1e6) + "").replace(".", ",") + " M" + unit;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = ((d / 1e9) + "").replace(".", ",") + " G" + unit;
                    break;
            }

            if (result.contains(",")) {
                if (result.indexOf(" ") - result.indexOf(",") >= decimals) {
                    result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf(",") + decimals + 1) + result.substring(result.indexOf(" "));
                }
                if (decimals <= 0)
                    result = result.replace(",", "");
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return "0 " + unit;
        }
    }
```

If I give `3866500.0` I want to get `3.9 M`, instead I get is `3,8 M`, because the algorithm doesn't round to the nearest upper value. I don't have a clue how to do that.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest java.text.NumberFormat:

```
public static String ToEngineeringNotation(double d, String unit, int decimals) {
    String m = "";
    if (d > 1000000000) {
        d = d / 1000000000;
        m = " G";
    } else if (d > 1000000) {
        d = d / 1000000;
        m = " M";
    } else  if (d > 1000) {
        d = d / 1000;
        m = " K";
    }
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    f.setGroupingUsed(false);
    f.setMinimumFractionDigits(decimals);
    f.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimals);
    return f.format(d) + m + " " + unit;
}
```

Note that NumberFormat will choose decimal separator depending on your locale, which is probably what you want. If you want it to be comma always then use NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the problem is that you are removing the decimals AFTER you make it a string. It's easier to do it the other way, in other words:

```
case 6: case 7: case 8:
    double divide = (d / 1e6d) * ;
    double roundFactor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    result = (Math.round(divide * roundFactor) / roundFactor) + "").replace(".", ",") + " M" + unit;
    break;
```

This is not the cleanest way but I wanted to show you the idea. Do rounding with math, not strings.

Comment: I changed my old answer (it was totally wrong), this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting your data to java.math.BigDecimal. It has several rounding modes, including rounding towards positive infinity. I believe your formatting would be easier starting from a decimal-scaled representation.